# readonly cells ... .. ......

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

1. Code is required
2. which type of value format is needed to enter in Excel cell, with one example
3. these are the coding stuff, also provided you an image where any can visualize how the problem look like. And in this problem we can't just use .SendKeys here it is more typical, because it have the Date-Month-Time, so help me out in this.
4. I tried, after removing "readonly" word in HTML .. then its working fine, but this is not the way can you edit in this code,

```
Sub google_search()
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    Dim GenderDD As Selenium.WebElement
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "https://abcd.com/"

    bot.FindElementbyName("sample_cdate").SendKeys "Value"
    
    Stop

End Function
```

Also giving Inspect of Targeted Site, for the reference

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" name="sample_cdate" id="sample_cdate" placeholder="Date and Time of Sample Collection" **readonly**="">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried, after removing "readonly" word in HTML .. then its working
> fine, but this is not the way can you edit in this code

You should replace `.SendKeys()` method:

```
'bot.FindElementbyName("patient_id").SendKeys Sheet1.Cells(row, 3).Value
bot.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", _
  Array(bot.FindElementById("sample_cdate"), _
    Format(Sheet1.Cells(row, 16).Value, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"))
```

As a readonly element, similar as on graphic WebBrowser, you cannot type input using `.SendKeys()`, but you can use JavaScript to set `.Value` attribute through programming.

As you show, your input id may be  id="`sample_rdate`", not `sample_cdate`.

Comment: can you please check, i have changed the lines, to just get your focus on main thing, which is date pattern hh:mm:ss

Comment: Your format() seems good for date-time  string. Should you then convert this input string into DateTime object on JavaScript, on PHP or other language? A universal format would be "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss"

Comment: Array(bot.FindElementById("sample_cdate"), (Sheet1.Cells(row, 16).Value, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss")) ....... showing a compile error on coma which is just after the Value

Comment: please check this on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746418/vba-excel-selenium-import-date-time-from-webpage-to-excel).. this query is  similar like this