# Import Date-Time from WebPage To Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Want to import date in excel from web, to just want to update my excel by this script.

```
Sub google_search()
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 2
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver

    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "https://abcd.com/"

'#1 Import Symptoms noted Date (normally)
    bot.FindElementById("date_of_onset_of_symptoms") = Format(Sheet1(row_index, 27).Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")

'#2 Import Collection Date web to excel (from set attribute because it is readonly cell)
    bot.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", _
    Array(bot.FindElementById("sample_cdate"), _
    Format(Sheet1(row_index, 23).Value, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss") 

Stop
End  Sub
```

#2 code is working only for Excel to Web date import, and it is working perfectly fine. But I want to reverse the action, Web to Excel !! & showing error.

- #1 line showing below error
- Run-time error '438:
  Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: If you are updating the spreadsheet then I would expect the sheet to be on the left of the equals eg `Sheet1.Cells(row_index, 27).Value 
= bot.FindElementById("date_of_onset_of_symptoms").Text`

Comment: thanks man, it help alot